# How do you change the Device the storyboard is viewed in

Tags: xcode, view, storyboard

I'm annoyed I even have to ask this. Where do I find a more detailed list of devices that the storyboard can be viewed in? I'm not talking about devices you can make the simulator as, I'm referring to within the storyboard. Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Be patient!

There is a bar under the storyboard editor which contains the scale size of the storyboard at the center (- 100% +). Exactly at the left side of that bar, there is a button which shows for example: "View as: iPhone 8 plus". Press that button to see a list of devices you can select to change the storyboard scenes for that.